# Proguard excluding classes from a library

Tags: android, android-proguard

Is there a way to exclude some classes, not excluding classes from obfuscation but to exclude them completely from the jar when compiling? I'm searching through all proguard manual but seems there is no documentation about it.

Comment: that could be done with gradle, I think

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vlad Matvienko's comment, it is indeed done with gradle sourceSet configuration.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/yourbrand/android/app/yourpackage/**'
        }
    }
}
```